# Problems installing Python 27 on Windows 7 - cannot add Python to PYTHON PATH

Tags: windows-7, python-2.7, installation

I installed [Python 2.7.3](http://www.python.org/download/) on my Windows 7 computer using the binary, the first link. After installing it, IDLE works but nothing else recognizes Python. For example, typing python at the command prompt returns the message "'Python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or bath file."

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7), I made sure that python 2.7 was in the PYTHONPATH environment variable. However, that didn't help.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure that you added python to the path and removed all conflicting versions?

Comment: You need to add `C:\Python27` (or wherever you installed Python on your computer) to `PATH` not `PYTHONPATH` as stated in Vladimir's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH` system variable is used by Python itself to find directories with installed packages.

`PATH` system variable is used by OS (particularly Windows) to find executables which can open certain files like `*.py` scripts.

So, you need to add directory with python.exe (for example `C:\Python27`) to `PATH` system (or user) variable and not to `PYTHONPATH`. It can be done the same way as described in the link you've found in the same tool window.

For example on my machine `PATH` system variable is set to `C:\Python27;C:\MinGW\bin;...`

Answer (score 0):

Like Vladimir commented, for [setting up python in windows](http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2011/10/15/setting-up-python-in-windows-7/), you need to add the directory where your python.exe is located (for example `C:\Python27`) to **PATH**

You can **confirm** if python is in your environment variables by looking at the output of echo `%path%`

Keep in mind that after editing the PATH variable using the control panel, you have to **open a new terminal**, as the setting will NOT be updated in existing terminals.

Another possibility is that you added the wrong path to the PATH variable. Verify it.

The bottom line is, if the directory of your python.exe is really in PATH, then running python will really work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your steps:

Right-click **Computer** and select **Properties**.

In the dialog box, select **Advanced System Settings**.

In the next dialog, select **Environment Variables**. In the **User Variables** section, edit the `PATH` statement to include this:

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;
```

Now, you can open a command prompt (`Start Menu|Accessorie`s or `Start Menu|Run|cmd`) and type:

```
C:\> python
```

That will load the Python interpreter!

Answer (score 0):

You can install for single user rather than choosing the option of "Install for all users". I was facing the same issue, but when I tried installing just for myself, I was able to install successfully.